# php get array elememnt using $$

Tags: php, arrays

i know this

```
$var1 = "10";
$var2 = "var1";
```

then 
      `echo $$var2` gives us 10

i want to this with array

i have array

```
 $intake_arr = array(5=>10,7=>20,8=>30,9=>40,10=>50,11=>60,12=>70);
```

i have some logic that will pick one array from set of array , all array will look like $intake_arr

if i do this `$target_arr = "intake_arr";`

then can `$$target_arr[5]` will yield 10?  i tried but  i didnt that 10 value, how can i achieve this with array

Comment: Whatever it is you're trying to do, this is almost certainly the wrong way to do it..

Comment: @mark i know this is wrong , i am getting errors, so   can you suggest better way to that ?

Comment: I believe he means your whole concept of doing stuff. Picking arrays from arrays to form arrays oO looks like a good case for a storage object or perhaps even a list or maybe..... a database oO

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your statement (`$$target_arr[5]`) is ambiguous. PHP doesn't know what you actually want to say: Do you mean: use `$target_arr[5]`'s value and prepend the `$`, to use that as a variable, or do you want to use the value of `$target_arr`, and get the fifth element of that array?
Obviously it's the latter, but PHP doesn't *know* that. In order to disambiguate your statement, you have to use curly braces:

```
${$target_arr}[5];
```

That'll yield 10. See the manual on [variable variables for details](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)

*Note:*
As people said in comments, and deleted answers: variable variables, like the one you're using is risky business. 9/10 it can, and indeed *should* be avoided. It makes your code harder to read, more error prone *and*, in combination with the those two major disadvantages, this is the killer: it makes your code ***incredibly hard to debug***.
If this is just a technical exercise, consider this note a piece of friendly advice. If you've gotten this from some sort of tutorial/blog or other type of online resource: never visit that site again.
If you're actually working on a piece of code, and you've decided to tackle a specific problem using variable vars, then perhaps post your code on [code-review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com), and let me know, I'll have a look and try to offer some constructive criticism to help you on your way, towards a better solution.

---

Since what you're actually trying to do is *copying* an array into another variable, then that's quite easy. PHP offers a variety of ways to do that:

*Copy by assignment:*
PHP copies arrays on assignment, by default, so that means that:

```
$someArray = range(1,10);//[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
$foo = $someArray;
```

Assigns a *copy* of `$someArray` to the variable `$foo`:

```
echo $foo[0], ' === ', $someArray[0];//echoes 1 === 1
$foo[0] += 123;
echo $foo[0], ' != ', $someArray[0];//echoes 123 != 1
```

I can change the value of one of the array's elements without that affecting the original array, because it was *copied*.
There is a risk to this, as you start working with JSON encoded data, chances are that you'll end up with something like:

```
$obj = json_decode($string);
echo get_class($obj));//echoes stdClass, you have an object
```

Objects are, by default, passed and assigned *by reference*, which means that:

```
$obj = new stdClass;
$obj->some_property = 'foobar';
$foo = $obj;
$foo->some_property .= '2';
echo $obj->some_property;//echoes foobar2!
```

Change a property through `$foo`, and the `$obj` object will change, too. Simply because they both reference exactly the same object.

*Slice the array:*
A more common way for front-end developers (mainly, I think, stemming from a JS habbit) is to use `array_slice`, which guarantees to return a copy of the array. with the added perk that you can specify how many of the elements you'll be needing in your copy:

```
$someArray = range(1,100);//"large" array
$foo = array_slice($someArray, 0);//copy from index 0 to the end
$bar = array_slice($someArray, -10);//copy last 10 elements
$chunk = array_slice($someArray, 20, 4);//start at index 20, copy 4 elements
```

If you don't want to *copy* the array, but rather *extract* a section out of the original you can `splice` the array (as in split + slice):

```
$extract = array_splice($someArray, 0, 10);
echo count($someArray);//echoes 90
```

This removes the first 10 elements from the original array, and assigns them to `$extract`

Spend some time browsing the countless (well, about a hundred) array functions PHP offers.

Comment: thanks for answer with explanation and hope you will help in future also

Comment: @ddw147: Seeing as I'm somewhat addicted to SO, I might well help you out in the future... And like I said in my last edit: if you're looking for some tips/criticism of your code, I'm an [active _"contributing"_ member of the codereview site, too](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/16133/elias-van-ootegem). I mainly focus on PHP there, lately, I'm more active in the C-tagged questions for this site :)

Comment: i read your note, if its unsafe then  can i copy one array to another, effectively than this. can you tell which is better variable variables or copying array

Comment: @ddw147: added some more explanation on the copying of arrays, splicing, reference pitfalls in some cases and what have you... hope some of it makes sense & is useful :)

Answer (score 5):

`${$target_arr}[5]`

[PHP: Variable variables](http://php.net/manual/language.variables.variable.php)

Comment: +1 for beating me to the same answer... I was busy typing up my, slightly more verbose, answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

```
$intake_arr = array(5=>10,7=>20,8=>30,9=>40,10=>50,11=>60,12=>70);
$target_arr = 'intake_arr';

print ${$target_arr}[5]; //it gives 10
```

For a simple variable, braces are optional.But when you will use a array element, you must use braces; `e.g.: ${$target_arr}[5];`.As a standard, braces are used if variable interpolation is used, instead of concatenation.Generally variable interpolation is slow, but concatenation may also be slower if you have too many variables to concatenate.Take a look here for php variable variables http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php