# PHP Replace {var['key']} in string with array variable

Tags: php, regex, replace, preg-replace

I want to replace not only simple variables but also **array** ones.
There is an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3763831/1056384) of [Alex Howansky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/453002/alex-howansky) about replace for simple variables:

```
$str = 'this is {TEST} a {THING} to test and a {array["key"]} var';

$TEST = 'one';
$THING = 'two';

$result = preg_replace('/\{([A-Z]+)\}/e', "$$1", $str);
```

It's work fine for {TEST} an {THING}.

For call variable variable for array I need `${$array}['key']` (https://stackoverflow.com/a/20216265/1056384). So I have tried to do second pass:

```
$result = preg_replace('/\{([a-z]+)\["([a-z]+)"\]\}/', "$\{$$1\}["$2"]", $result);
```

But in the output I have get the string `$\{$array\}["key"]` instead of value of $array["key"].

How to replace substrings in template with array variables?

Comment: `$($array)["key"]` is not valid PHP.

Comment: Normally to interpolate an array, you have to surround it in curly braces, e.g. `"Your name is {$names['key']}"` but I can't get the interpolation to work inside `preg_replace`. This is as close as I've gotten, but it's still giving me an error `PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '1' (T_LNUMBER), expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) or '$'` Maybe this will point you in the right direction: `$result = preg_replace('/\{([a-z]+)\["([a-z]+)"\]\}/', "{$$1['$2']}", $result);`

Comment: @AbraCadaver https://stackoverflow.com/a/20216265/1056384 my fault i need curly braces `${$array}['key']`

Comment: Thank you @Kita. Maybe this will work with preg_replace_callback function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't get it to parse correctly with just `preg_replace` so I used a callback:

```
$str = 'this is {TEST} a {THING} to test and a {array["key"]} var';

$array['key'] = 'something';

$result = preg_replace_callback('/\{([a-z]+)\["([a-z]+)"\]\}/',
                                function($m) use($array){
                                    return ${$m[1]}[$m[2]];
                                },
                                $str);
```

If you don't know the name of the array to pass into the function you will need to make sure it's defined in the global scope and then access it that way:

```
$result = preg_replace_callback('/\{([a-z]+)\["([a-z]+)"\]\}/',
                                function($m) {
                                    ${$m[1]} = $GLOBALS[$m[1]];
                                    return ${$m[1]}[$m[2]];
                                },
                                $str);
```

Comment: O! Cool. It's works with predefined name of $array. Can you propose a elegant solution for situation when we don't know the "array" name?

Comment: Edited with a solution if the array is global.